# insert/replace once cycling

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, enter

I'd like to change the behaviour of EMACS auto-complete.
What I want is to get it worked like as Vim's.
In other words, when cycling amongst candidates, it doesn't insert(or replace) the selected one in the current position while Vim does. Emacs always requires pressing Enter key.
If you have a good idea to mimic Vim's, could I get it from you, please?

Comment: (This comment refers to the third party `auto-complete` package.  If you're talking about something else you should clarify.)  `auto-complete` doesn't require `RET` by default.  I'm not familiar with Vim so I don't know what its completion is like, but the way you describe it sounds very much like `auto-complete`'s default config.  Maybe try `(setq ac-expand-on-auto-complete t ac-auto-show-menu t)`.  `M-x customize-group RET auto-complete RET` for more options and descriptions.

Comment: I tried so as you left. However it didn't work.
What I meant is automatic expansion on cycling thru candidates in a popup window.

Comment: Again, that's what `auto-complete` does by default.  As you cycle through the candidates (which are displayed in a popup menu), the current match is automatically expanded.  You need to explain in detail how this differs from what you want.